# creating a multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a multi-dimensional associative array in javascript. I have created a variable inputs with the following structure but when I access it some where else I get undefined. I don't think there is anything wrong with the structure

```
                            inputs = {
                                indexe: {"input_name":$(input).val()},
                            };

  //where indexe is        indexe = indexe + 1;
```

secondly when I try to access inputs[0]["input_name"] I get undefined. Why is that? My main question is that whether the array structure is correct and it should give the values correctly? There is no scope problem here.

Comment: Put it in a `console.log()` and look at the structure. What does it say?

Comment: You are creating object not array

Comment: *"associative array in javascript"* -- Javascript does not provide [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). What you are creating is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP @axiac In js objects are often used to create pseudo-associative arrays, since you can access objects using `[]`. I have sometimes even heard lecturers call them associative arrays. The problem here is the way he creates them and not the basic idea behind it and should be rather obvious once you output the whole object.

Comment: @SourceOverflow if you can provide the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked you to use `console.log()` on the input object, because that will make it clear what you problem is:

```js
// your (wrong) way

const indexe = 5;
const yourway = {
  indexe: {
    "input_name": 'value' // I used a string so I wouldn't have to import jQuery for this
  },
};

console.log('Your original version: ', yourway);

// using a real array, this will have a lot of undefined elements

const arrayV = [];
arrayV[indexe] = {
  "input_name": 'value'
}

console.log('Array version: ', arrayV);

// using an object correctly
const objectV1 = {
  [indexe]: {
    "input_name": 'value'
  },
};

console.log('Object version: ', objectV1);

// you can add more to it like so:
objectV1[7] = {
  "input_name": 'value'
};

console.log('After adding another entry: ', objectV1);

// you also don't need to create a new object with an already existing element. This will suffice:
const objectV2 = {};
objectV2[indexe] = {
  "input_name": 'value'
};

console.log('2. Object version: ', objectV2);

// imortant note on the object versions: length is not defined for objects
console.log('Object version 1 length: ', objectV1.length);
console.log('Object version 2 length: ', objectV2.length);
```

Your problem simply was that it didn't use the value of `indexe`, but rather that as the name of a property. I have also included the array version, even though that is not an associative array (and as people in the comments have pointed out, neither are the object versions, really).

---

P.s. I used ES6 Syntax. It is rather widely supported, but I would still recommend going for at least ES5. (There are pre-processors for that)
If you want to make it ES5-valid, replace `const` with `var` and don't use the `objectV1`-version.